# Collision Detection Between Two 3D Disks In Space

Tags: 3d, collision, detection, disk

I would like to develop an algorithm for performing collision detection between two 3D disks in 3D space. Is it possible to suggest an analytical method so I can develop this program.

Thanks,

Comment: Please describe _in detail_ what information is given at any point and in what form?

Comment: @jAlex Thank you so much for providing such a detailed answer. What I meant by 3D disk is that what if the disk has a thickness. This makes collision detection so difficult. I developed a code that fills the 3D disk with a lot of spheres and I perform the collision detection between spheres which takes so log to complete. Your thought on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can adapt my answer to include thickness easily. Modify the `Disk.Containts()` function to check for `DistanceTo(point)<= Thickness/2` and that is it. See edits below.

Comment: @jAlex Again thank you so much for your answer. I will rewrite this code in MATLAB since I generate random numbers in there.

Comment: See my updates in my answer, with link to `Matlab` code for the general geometry stuff.

Answer (score 3):

So each of the disks sits on top of an infinite plane, each with a normal vector and a distance to the origin. Where the two planes meet, they form a line.

This line projects the centers **c**<sub>1</sub> and **c**<sub>2</sub> into two points on the line **p**<sub>1</sub> and **p**<sub>2</sub> with perpendicular distances *h*<sub>1</sub> and *h*<sub>2</sub>. The distance between the projected points is *l*.

[image: fig1]

The common line will contain the contact point if the disks are in contact. If they are not in contact, or they are interpenetrating, this point **p**<sub>C</sub> is the point on the line closest to both disk centers at the same time.

[image: fig2]

To find the distance *t*<sub>1</sub> from  **p**<sub>1</sub> to **p**<sub>C</sub> use similar triangles to solve (*t*<sub>1</sub>)/*h*<sub>1</sub> = (*l* - *t*<sub>1</sub>)/*h*<sub>2</sub>

```
t_1 = h_1*ell/(h_1+h_2)
```

From the distance *t*<sub>1</sub> and the common line direction, point **p**<sub>C</sub> is calculated, *and then the two disks are intersecting if their respective distances to their centers are equal or less than their radii*.

```
intersect = ( distance(c_1-p_C)<=R_1 ) && ( distance(c_2-p_C)<=R_2 )
```

There is a special case when both circles centers lie on the common line, which also needs to be considered. The full solution in **`C#`** is

#### Main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var disk_1 = new Disk(Point.Origin, Vector3.UnitZ, 1);
        var disk_2 = new Disk(
            Point.Origin + Vector3.UnitY,
            Vector3.UnitY,
            0.6f);
        if (Disk.Intersect(disk_1, disk_2))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Crash");
        }
    }
```

#### Disk

```
using System.Numerics;
public class Disk : Plane
{
    public Disk(Point center, Vector3 normal, float radius, float thickness)
        : base(center, normal)
    {
        this.Center=center;
        this.Radius=radius;
        this.Thickness = thickness;
    }

    public Point Center { get; }
    public float Radius { get; }
    public float Thickness { get; }

    public bool Containts(Point point)
    {
        if (DistanceTo(point)<= Thickness/2)
        {
            var d = (point - Center).Length();
            return d<=Radius;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Intersect(Disk disk_1, Disk disk_2)
    {
        var commonLine = Line.Meet(disk_1, disk_2);
        var p_1 = commonLine.Project(disk_1.Center);
        var p_2 = commonLine.Project(disk_2.Center);
        var ell = p_1.DistanceTo(p_2);
        var h_1 = commonLine.DistanceTo(disk_1.Center);
        var h_2 = commonLine.DistanceTo(disk_2.Center);
        if (Math.Abs(h_1+h_2)>1e-8)
        {
            var t_1 = h_1*ell/(h_1+h_2);
            var contact = p_1 - commonLine.Direction * t_1;
            return disk_1.Containts(contact) && disk_2.Containts(contact);
        }
        else
        {
            return ell <= disk_1.Radius + disk_2.Radius;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Geometry

```
using System.Numerics;
public class Point 
{
    public Vector3 Vector { get; }
    public float Scalar { get; }

    public Point(Vector3 position)
        : this(position, 1) { }
    public Point(Vector3 vector, float scalar)
    {
        this.Vector = vector;
        this.Scalar=scalar;
    }
    public Point(Vector4 coordinates)
        : this(new Vector3(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, coordinates.Z), coordinates.W)
    { }
    public Point(Plane plane)
        : this(-plane.Scalar*plane.Vector, plane.Vector.LengthSquared())
    { }
    public Point(Line line)
        : this(Vector3.Cross(line.Vector, line.Moment), line.Vector.LengthSquared())
    { }

    public static implicit operator Point(Vector3 position)
        => new Point(position, 1);
    public static implicit operator Point(Vector4 coordinates)
        => new Point(coordinates);

    public static readonly Point Origin = new Point(Vector3.Zero, 1);

    public static Point Meet(Plane plane, Line line)
    {
        return new Point(
            Vector3.Cross(line.Moment, plane.Vector)+plane.Scalar*line.Vector,
            -Vector3.Dot(plane.Vector, line.Vector));
    }
    public static Point Meet(Plane plane_1, Plane plane_2, Plane plane_3)
    {
        return Meet(plane_1, Line.Meet(plane_2, plane_3));
    }

    public float Magnitude { get => Math.Abs(Scalar); }
    public Vector3 Position { get => Vector/Scalar; }
    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => (Scalar*point.Vector - point.Scalar*Vector).Length()/(Scalar*point.Scalar);
    public float DistanceTo(Plane plane)
        => (Vector3.Dot(plane.Vector, Vector) + Scalar*plane.Scalar)/(Scalar*plane.Vector.Length());
    public float DistanceTo(Line line)
        => (Vector3.Cross(line.Vector, Vector) + Scalar * line.Moment).Length()/(Scalar*line.Vector.Length());
    public static Point operator +(Point point, Vector3 delta)
        => new Point(point.Vector + point.Scalar*delta, point.Scalar);
    public static Vector3 operator -(Point point, Point @base)
        => point.Position - @base.Position;

}
public class Plane 
{
    public Vector3 Vector { get; }
    public float Scalar { get; }

    public Plane(Vector3 vector, float scalar)
    {
        this.Vector=vector;
        this.Scalar=scalar;
    }
    public Plane(Vector4 coordinates)
        : this(new Vector3(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, coordinates.Z), coordinates.W)
    { }
    public Plane(Point point, Vector3 normal)
        : this(normal, -Vector3.Dot(point.Position, normal))
    { }

    public Plane(Point point)
        : this(-point.Scalar*point.Vector, point.Vector.LengthSquared())
    { }
    public Plane(Line line)
        : this(Vector3.Cross(line.Moment, line.Vector), line.Moment.LengthSquared())
    { }
    public static implicit operator Plane(Vector4 coordinates)
        => new Plane(coordinates);

    public static Plane Join(Point point, Line line)
    {
        return new Plane(
            Vector3.Cross(line.Vector, point.Position) + line.Moment,
            -Vector3.Dot(point.Position, line.Moment));
    }
    public static Plane Join(Point point_1, Point point_2, Point point_3)
    {
        return Join(point_1, Line.Join(point_2, point_3));
    }
    public float Magnitude { get => Vector.Length(); }
    public Vector3 Normal { get => Vector3.Normalize(Vector); }
    public float Offset { get => -Scalar/Magnitude; }
    public Vector3 Position
    {
        get => Normal*Offset;
    }
    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => point.DistanceTo(this);

    public Point Project(Point point)
    {
        float t = Vector3.Dot(Normal, point.Position)-Offset;
        return point.Position - Normal*t;
    }
}
public class Line 
{
    public Vector3 Vector { get; }
    public Vector3 Moment { get; }

    public Line(Vector3 vector, Vector3 moment)
    {
        this.Vector=vector;
        this.Moment=moment;
    }

    public static Line Ray(Point point, Vector3 direction)
    {
        return new Line(direction,
            Vector3.Cross(point.Position, direction));
    }

    public static Line Join(Point point_1, Point point_2)
    {
        return new Line(
            point_2.Position-point_1.Position,
            Vector3.Cross(point_1.Position, point_2.Position));
    }
    public static Line Meet(Plane plane_1, Plane plane_2)
    {
        return new Line(
            Vector3.Cross(plane_1.Vector, plane_2.Vector),
            plane_2.Vector*plane_1.Scalar-plane_1.Vector*plane_2.Scalar);
    }
    public Point Along(float travel)
        => Position.Position + Direction * travel;
    public float Magnitude { get => Vector.Length(); }
    public Vector3 Direction { get => Vector3.Normalize(Vector); }
    public Point Position
    {
        get => new Point(this);
    }
    public float DistanceTo(Point point)
        => point.DistanceTo(this);
    public float DistanceTo(Line line)
        => (Vector3.Dot(Vector, line.Moment) + Vector3.Dot(line.Vector, Moment))/Vector3.Cross(Vector, line.Vector).Length();

    public Point Project(Point point)
    {
        return Along(Vector3.Dot(Direction, point.Position-Position.Position));
    }
}
```

<sub>Math above is based on [Foundations of Game Engine Development, by Eric Lengyel](https://foundationsofgameenginedev.com/#fged1).</sub>

#### Updates

- Added thickness to the disk properties, and use it to check if a point is contained with a disk.
- Link to MATALB code [Class definitions for **Point3.m**, **Plane3.m** and **Line3.m**](https://gist.github.com/johnalx/d762f38c54a93f0e4798a19059aee99a) I wrote a long time ago. There might be some things missing, but it might give you a good starting point. Nothing specific about disks just the framework for geometry with homogeneous coordinates.