# Detect if a 3D point with radius is passed by a line of two 3D points? (C#)

Tags: c#

I have three 3D points, just say p1, p2, and p3. I am able to make a line that connects p1 and p2. Then, the p3 will be in between the p1 and p2 but not collinear. I want to know if the p3 is close to the line. How to check it?
[image]

Comment: Is this in plain C#, or e.g. Unity?

Comment: For your reference: https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/Geometry%20Concepts%20part%201:%20Basic%20Concepts

Comment: Also [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67116330/13813219) with a geometry toolbox code for handling Points, Planes & Lines and the relationships between them (including distances). The math is based on [Foundations of Game Engine Development, by Eric Lengyel](https://foundationsofgameenginedev.com/#fged1).

Comment: @AKX it is in plain C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2D

You're just finding the height of a triangle. Fortunately you can instantly google the formula:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

> [image]

### 3D

Again, the formula is widely available

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html

[image]

### Generally ..

Here's the bible that all game programmers have to memorize by heart!

[http://amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Third/dp/1435458869](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869)

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code (formulas in this case) as images. Also, OP has a 3D problem and the quoted formula is 2D. It would probably be useful for OP to get the 3D derivation.

Comment: @AKX - I literally don't know how to post formulas like that on here!  Perhaps someone can edit it in.

Comment: @Fattie thanks buddy, it's working. I am not a game developer :D.